# Navigate user to particular message in channel upon clicking a button in Personal Chat adaptive card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am sending a message to the user using an Adaptive card. With the click of a button, I would like to redirect the user to a particular message in the channel. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

On click of button you can add a deeplink of message in channel

Use below deep link format to navigate to a particular conversation within channel thread:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message//?tenantId=&groupId=&parentMessageId=&teamName=&channelName=&createdTime=

Example: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message//1648741500652?tenantId=&groupId=&parentMessageId=1648741500652&teamName=&channelName=&createdTime=1648741500652

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-deep-links-to-channel-conversation